# Relation between pseudo-dimension and Rademacher complexity

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, learning-theory

With techniques of Dudley's entropy bound and Haussler's upper bound one can show that there exists a constant $C$ such that any class of $\{0,1\}$ indicator functions with Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension $d$ has Rademacher complexity upper-bounded by $C\sqrt{\frac{d}{m}}$, where $m$ is the number of points. (source e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_complexity)

Does similar hold for bounded interval $[0,1]$-valued functions with pseudo-dimension $d$? For definition of pseudo-dimension I'm following these [lecture notes](http://www.shivani-agarwal.net/Teaching/E0370/Aug-2011/Lectures/5.pdf).
(The reason I think so is that with the same Dudley's integral bound and then bounding the covering number with fat shattering dimension, which in turn is upper bounded by the pseudo-dimension)

Comment: Have you tried an example where pseudo dimension and VC dimension disagree? In such an example, will Rademacher's bound still be tight?